# How come Koro sensei had tomato juice inside jail?

Tags: assassination-classroom

In Assassination Classroom Season 2, episode 8, Tadaomi was fighting with Reaper, and then there was one incident where he faked his death from blood loss with the help of Koro-sensei. And then later it is shown that Koro-sensei was drinking tomato juice, and with the help of his one tentacles he faked that scene and helped Tadaomi.

So my question is: how did he get that tomato juice? Is it possible that he was keeping it from the start, or did he try to escape and then got one?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Explained in the manga:

[image: Chapter 109]

He bought it beforehand.

Comment: please see our policy on copyrighted material: http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/questions/404/how-do-we-deal-with-copyrighted-material-on-our-site. I removed your link, but you may like to replace it with a more legitimate source

Comment: Sorry about that. But I don't have the manga and how would I go about this? I guess he'll have to search it himself.

Answer (score 0):

Koro-sensei was

> the legendary assassin called Death God.

In assassination it is important to know your enemy (name, skill, habits, etc), and location (geographic, building structure, surroundings) to ensure that the assassination can be do successfully.

It was revealed later that the current Death God

> was Koro-sensei's first student.

which means that Koro-sensei knows perfectly well the extend of his abilities.

Thus, it is very possible that Koro-sensei had the tomato juice prepared beforehand. This fits the fact that they are underground, which means that Koro shouldn't be able to get tomato juice there.

Comment: This is the semi-logical deduction after watching the anime. I don't think it was particularly stated at all why and how he had a bottle of tomato juice.

Comment: Possibility I agree, also there were many scene where the creator showed various events in well detailed for example, when students were giving exam then for every question they were showing it like those students were battling with whole army. So in simple words there are few events were they tried to explain few events in much attractive way. So it might be possible that it is something related like that just to add some fun and making it more attractive.